# Are there any todo list desktop widgets?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, widgets

Are there any todo list / notepad desktop widgets? Bonus points if it can sync with Google's tasks list!

Answer (score 2):

You can install `Google Calendar gadget` to get google tasks on the desktop. Check this url for more info: 
http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/googlecalendar2.html

UPDATE: You can also use systray apps like Googsystray and CloudSN. have a look at here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/googsystray-1-3-0-released-with-tasks-support-fixes/

Answer (score 1):

There is a great one for KDE if you have Kubuntu called Google/Gmail tasks or something like that.

Or if you're adventurous and running Unity, you might try the directions here:

- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-run-kde-plasma-widgets-in-ubuntu-unity/ to get plasma widgets running under Ubuntu so you can use the KDE one.

Answer (score 0):

I use AWN for my bottom of the screen icons and this has a built in to-do list applet (only useful to you if you use AWN).