# The current state of ToDo list application, desktop widgets (2018)

Tags: productivity

On my iPhone I use Things
Is there anything similar for Ubuntu desktops?

I'm on Ubuntu mate 18.04.

A search only turned up this 7 year old post
[Are there any todo list desktop widgets?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20032/are-there-any-todo-list-desktop-widgets)

Comment: and it did not show you https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/ubuntu-18-04-new-app-to-do  ? GNOME To Do and it is default in Ubuntu as of 18.04

Comment: Thanks. Funny, as mentioned on Ubuntu Mate and don't recall seeing this.

Comment: @Rinzwind Not much help to us on Ubuntu MATE unless we want to pull in tons of dependencies